# Setting sqlite config SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED returns SQLITE_MISUSE on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios5

With the release of iOS 5 we are getting more and more errors when setting the serialized option for the sqlite database (so its save to be used for multithreading). We are getting SQLITE_MISUSE error code on sqlite3_config. Has someone noticed this odd behavior? And does someone know how I can fix this? It works perfectly fine on previous iOS versions.

here is the code:

```
- (sqlite3 *)getNewDBConnection {
    NSLog(@"sqlite3 lib version: %s", sqlite3_libversion());

    //sqlite3_config() has to be called before any sqlite3_open calls.

    if (sqlite3_threadsafe() > 0) {
        int retCode = sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
        if (retCode == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Can now use sqlite on multiple threads, using the same connection");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"setting sqlite thread safe mode to serialized failed!!! return code: %d", retCode);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Your SQLite database is not compiled to be threadsafe.");
    }

    sqlite3 *newDBconnection;

    // Open the database
    if (sqlite3_open([[self getDatabaseFilePath] UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened :)");
    } else {
        sqlite3_close(newDBconnection);
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database :(");
    }

    return newDBconnection; 
}
```

and this is the output:

```
sqlite3 lib version: 3.7.7
setting sqlite thread safe mode to serialized failed!!! return code: 21
Database Successfully Opened :)
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, and calling sqlite3_initialize() after sqlite3_config() does not resolve the issue. The call to config() still returns SQLITE_MISUSE (code 21). Anyone was able to figure this out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I struggled long and hard with this as well and finally got the solution.

As @enobufs said, `sqlite3_config()` needs to be called before `sqlite3_initialize()`. However, the OS might initialize SQLite for us so I also do a `sqlite3_shutdown()` before the `sqlite3_config()`.

1. `sqlite3_shutdown()`
2. `sqlite3_config()`
3. `sqlite3_initialize()`.

Then its also necessary to use the same connection for every query as it is the access to the database connection that gets serialized. As described here http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqliteconfigserialized

So I create a connection as soon as the app starts up and the pass that connection to every class that needs it.

Comment: thanks for the tipp. it seems to work now but this needs further testing if it really fixes our problem and it will not have any side effects.

Comment: @naudec at what point in the application do you call the 3 methods? is it in the `appdeleage.cs`? and what parameters do you pass into `sqlite3_config()`

Comment: Apologies @user1 I don't have access to this codebase anymore and it's too long ago for me to remember 

Answer (score 1):

Is the `sqlite3_config()` called before `sqlite3_initialize()`? The function returns `SQLITE_MISUSE` if called after `sqlite3_initialize()` and before `sqlite3_shutdown()`. See http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html for more details.

Comment: I'm not calling any of these methods. It works fine in previous versions.

Comment: I wasn't calling *_initialize()/*_shutdown() functions with earlier versions of ios either and working fine. But multithread operations failed with ios 5. Apparently, sqlite3_initialize() is called automatically if the library is compiled without SQLITE_OMIT_AUTOINIT. To resolve my problem with ios, I explicitly called sqlite3_initialize() after sqlite3_config() before any other sqlite3 function calls. Now my sqlite3_config() returns SQLITE_OK and multithreaded access working properly on ios 5. I agree something has changed with ios5. Good luck!