# Which threading mode is Sqlite for iOS compiled in?

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, ios5

The page http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html mentions:

- Single-thread
- Multi-thread
- Serialized

Which mode is the sqlite that is integrated in iOS 5 compiled in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so sqlite3_threadsafe() returns 2 so it is compiled with SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD on iOS. That is unfortunate, I would have liked Serialized.

sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED) unfortunately gives me SQLITE_MISUSE

Comment: Try to open the DB connection with full mutex: `sqlite3_open_v2(sqliteFilePath, &sqlite, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, NULL);`

Answer (score 3):

As per this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799021/40444

It appears you can do the following:

```
sqlite3_shutdown();
if (sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"sqlite configured to be threadsafe);
}
sqlite3_initialize();
```

However it's unclear if this officially works.

Comment: unfortunately logging `sqlite3_threadsafe()` does not show any difference after the setting's been applied...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Multi-thread.
We can check by using sqlite3_threadsafe(), which returns 2.

```
0 - Single-thread
2 - Multi-thread
1 - Serialized
```

---

Q: @Ben Marten 
*"unfortunately logging sqlite3_threadsafe() does not show any
 difference after the setting's been applied... "*

A: sqlite3_threadsafe() only reports on the compile-time mutex setting
 of the [SQLITE_THREADSAFE] flag.

> The return value of the sqlite3_threadsafe() interface is determined
>   by the compile-time threading mode selection. If single-thread mode is
>   selected at compile-time, then sqlite3_threadsafe() returns false. If
>   either the multi-thread or serialized modes are selected, then
>   sqlite3_threadsafe() returns true. The sqlite3_threadsafe() interface
>   predates the multi-thread mode and start-time and run-time mode
>   selection and so is unable to distinguish between multi-thread and
>   serialized mode nor is it able to report start-time or run-time mode
>   changes.